# How do you get a SQLite3 connection to an encrypted database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a simple SQLite3 database using SQLiteManager. The database is encrypted with an AES 128 encryption, done within the SQLiteManager program. My question is, can you specify the encryption password in the python connection string?

```
con=sqlite3.connect("secrets.sqlite")
```

Returns a connection, but with no data accessible within the database.

Since there are multiple options out there to encrypt a database, not just limited to what was done in SQLiteManager, I want to know if you can add password information to the standard `sqlite3.connect()` function  in order to access database information.

Comment: no ... sqlite in general does not support encryption .... not sure what SQLiteManager is doing ... but its their own version of "secure sqlite" ... also what do you mean by no data accessible? does it give you an error if you try a query? or you get junk back or?

Comment: Okay, suppose that answers the question then. If you actually mark that as an answer I'll accept it. No data accessible means that all queries just return empty dataset. Same behavior as when I do it from the command line via a sqlite> prompt.

Comment: I added it as an answer... all though its hardly a helpful answer ...

Comment: [SQLiteManager appears to be using SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2014/09/10/announcing-sqlcipher-support-in-sqlitemanager.html).
I haven't tried it, but [pysqlcipher](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlcipher) might be what you are looking for. See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986403/190597).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no ... sqlite in general does not support encryption .... not sure what SQLiteManager is doing ... but its their own version of "secure sqlite" ...